# USB Otg Android and creating an autorun to copy the device

Tags: android, usb, autorun

I am interested in quickly copying an android device onto a USB Flash Drive

I know with windows I can create an autorun to copy specific files or folders

what I am wanting to do is plug the usb flash drive in and it copies the android device contents.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for this in Android. Considering the security issues involved in Windows autorun, this lack of support is not surprising.